# Load Properties in propertyGrid from file

Tags: c#, wpf, propertygrid

We are developing an IDE and we want to load properties of any component selected in canvas.

The problem is that every component is having different properties and are listed in a file like,
`{"PropertyName",  "Type" } 
 {"NumberProp"  ,  "int"  }
 {"DemoProp"    , "String"}`

Is there any way to dynamically load these properties from file to property grid ?

These properties will also be having group name to describe category too.

Comment: What property grid are you using? I don't think there is one built-in for WPF (there is for WinForms).

Comment: Currently using DevExpress PropertyGrid, recommend me anyother Propertygrid that can resolve this problem ?

Comment: I'm sure that you will need write some code anyway.